# Java string tokenization: need to modify regex pattern to remove short tokens

Tags: java, regex

I need to tokenize a `String` as follows:

1. Split by whitespace
2. Remove all non-letters
3. Remove all letter tokens of length less than N

Looks like I can get #1 and #2 by

```
String str = "blah blah";
String p1 = "[^a-zA-Z ]";
String p2 = "\\s+";
String[] tokens = str.replaceAll(p1, "").split(p2);
```

Can I modify `p1` to also do #3? As an alternative, I can do

```
String p1 = "[^a-zA-Z ]";
String p2 = "\\s+";
String p3 = ""\\b\\w{1,2}\\b";
String[] tokens = str.replaceAll(p1, "").replaceAll(p3, "").split(p2);
```

Is `p3` even correct?

I also prefer to avoid adding another pattern (which would also be less efficient, right?)

Comment: `replaceAll()` takes `String` arguments, not `Pattern`.

Comment: I have come up with [some code](http://ideone.com/IRQQG2), please check.

Comment: Your `p3` pattern is correct. So fare I can not find any regex to combine `p1`  and `p3` that works for `3A-BC` string. Also before `split()` your string need to be trimmed  for leading/trailing white-spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `#2` and `#3` as:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\b[^a-zA-Z]*(?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z ]*){1,2}\\b|[^a-zA-Z ]+", "");
```

This will remove all non-letter/non-space and all less than 3 character words.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQ6kS3/2)

Comment: How does a `replaceAll()` call implement *"1. Split by whitespace"*?

Comment: Sorry I meant combine `#2` and `#3`

Comment: Ok, for N=3 (what `{1,2}` means) and input `A BC DEF G12 H3J4K`, I'd expect result `[DEF, HJK]`, but you'd also keep `G`.

Comment: @anubhava So does this pattern replace all 3?

Comment: Yes it does, [as you can see in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQ6kS3/1)

Comment: @anubhava +1 for the link!

Comment: @anubhava I have included a fixed version of your solution in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34754390/5221149) that handles all Unicode letters and correctly handle whitespaces, not just spaces.

Comment: @MaxZoom: [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQ6kS3/3)

Comment: Getting better, but still matches `3A-BC` string, which should be saved as `ABC`

Comment: `3A-BC` is not a word because `-` is not considered a word character. I can tweak the regex to treat `3A-BC` as single token but that may not be what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

No, `p3` is not correct, because you eliminate some whitespace before splitting, you don't account for leading whitespace which causes `split()` to return empty leading value, and you hard-code `N`.

Test with this input string:

```
String input = "  A Aa AaA AaAa  \r\n" +
               "  1 11 111 1111  \r\n" +
               "  A1 A1a A1c1 A1a1A A1c1A1 A1a1A1a  \r\n" +
               "  AeA\tAeAeA  ";
```

Below are 4 implementations, with my solution listed last. They will produce the following output when called with `n = 3`:

```
[AaA, AaAa, AaA, AcA, AaAa, AeA, AeAeA]   ← literalInterpretation
{, AaA, AaAa, AaA, AcA, AaAa, AeAAeAeA}   ← fromQuestion
{, AaA, AaAa, AaA, AcA, AaAa, AeAAeAeA}   ← answerByAnubhava
{AaA, AaAa, AaA, AcA, AaAa, AeA, AeAeA}   ← answerByAnubhavaFixedByMe
{AaA, AaAa, AaA, AcA, AaAa, AeA, AeAeA}   ← myAnswer
```

---

```java
private static void literalInterpretation(int n, String input) {
    // 1. Split by whitespace
    String[] values = input.split("(?U)\\s+"); // Whitespaces (unicode character class)

    // 2. Remove all non-letters
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        values[i] = values[i].replaceAll("\\P{L}+", ""); // Non-letters (unicode category)

    // 3. Remove all letter tokens of length less than N
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String value : values)
        if (value.length() >= n)
            tokens.add(value);

    System.out.println(tokens);
}
```

```java
private static void fromQuestion(int n, String input) {
    String p1 = "[^a-zA-Z ]";
    String p2 = "\\s+";
    String p3 = "\\b\\w{1," + (n-1) + "}\\b";
    String[] tokens = input.replaceAll(p1, "").replaceAll(p3, "").split(p2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
}
```

```java
private static void answerByAnubhava(int n, String input) {
    String str = input.replaceAll("\\b(?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z ]*){1," + (n-1) + "}\\b|[^a-zA-Z ]+", "");
    String[] tokens = str.split("\\s+");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
}
```

```java
private static void answerByAnubhavaFixedByMe(int n, String input) {
    String[] tokens = input.replaceAll("(?U)\\b[^\\p{L}\\s]*(?:\\p{L}[^\\p{L}\\s]*){1," + (n-1) + "}\\b|[^\\p{L}\\s]+", "")
                           .replaceFirst("(?U)^\\s+", "")
                           .split("(?U)\\s+");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
}
```

```java
private static void myAnswer(int n, String input) {
    String[] tokens = input.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{L}\\s]", "")            // 2. Remove all non-letters (excl. whitespace)
                           .replaceAll("\\b\\w{1," + (n-1) + "}\\b", "")  // 3. Remove all tokens of length less than N
                           .replaceFirst("(?U)^\\s+", "")                 // Remove leading whitespace
                           .split("(?U)\\s+");                            // 1. Split by whitespace

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
}
```

Comment: Since you are handling unicode characters, it may be nice to handle [unicode whitespace characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-int-) as well.

Comment: @anubhava I am. The `(?U)` is equivalent to [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) which modifies `\s` to be same as `\p{Whitespace}` (see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties).